# How to output a String into an HTML document page from a native Function API

Tags: javascript, api

I am practicing my API skills and decided to make a Crypto Currency calculator (simple enough).

I have been stuck on how to output the value that I want in my HTML doc to a specific DIV "id". To the best of my knowledge everything seems like it should be working but when I try to output the desired value onto my innerHTML it outputs nothing.

I am trying to output this value {"USD":1.94} onto my HTML. However I am not skilled enough to properly call this value from its respective storage. I was hoping if anyone can help me fix this. Thank you.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Crypto Calc</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Header
    </header>
    <div id="pbf-main-container">

    </div>
    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
             <script src="pbf.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
// Get the HTTP Header Request for CryptoCompare API
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            document.body.className = 'ok';
            console.log(request.responseText); // This is the outcome of the curreny value
        } else if (!isValid(this.response) && this.status == 0) {
            document.body.className = 'error offline';
            console.log("The computer appears to be offline.");                
        } else {
            document.body.className = 'error';
        }
    }
};
request.open("GET", 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XRP&tsyms=USD' , true);
request.send(null);
// Putting the outcome of the HTTP request into a Variable
var XRPUSD = request.responseText;
// This it to integrate it with the index.html
// console.log(XRPUSD);
document.getElementById("pbf-main-container").innerHTML = XRPUSD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move last five lines

```
// Putting the outcome of the HTTP request into a Variable
var XRPUSD = request.responseText;
// This it to integrate it with the index.html
// console.log(XRPUSD);
document.getElementById("pbf-main-container").innerHTML = XRPUSD;
```

after this line

```
document.body.className = 'ok';
// Putting the outcome of the HTTP request into a Variable
var XRPUSD = request.responseText;
// This it to integrate it with the index.html
// console.log(XRPUSD);
document.getElementById("pbf-main-container").innerHTML = XRPUSD;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working now @Waqar Ul Aziz . I will up vote and accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: By any chance would you know how to convert the outcome into a float? I tried using parseFloat and parseInt but it is returning "NaN" for me in the console. I added this line of code inside the function. "var p = parseInt(XRPUSD);"

Comment: Never mind I figured this one out. ANSWER: "var p = parseFloat(XRPUSD.slice(7));"

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the HTTP Header Request for CryptoCompare API
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            document.body.className = 'ok';
            console.log(request.responseText); // This is the outcome of the curreny value
      // Putting the outcome of the HTTP request into a Variable
      var XRPUSD = request.responseText;
            // beautify JSON object
      document.getElementById("pbf-main-container").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(XRPUSD,null,2);
        } else if (!isValid(this.response) && this.status == 0) {
            document.body.className = 'error offline';
            console.log("The computer appears to be offline.");                
        } else {
            document.body.className = 'error';
        }
    }
};
request.open("GET", 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XRP&tsyms=USD' , true);
request.send(null);
```

Http request is async,so you